# How to Read Photos for Deep Learning on Google Cloud Platform Compute Engine VM Instance, Through Jupyter Lab

Tags: virtual-machine, google-compute-engine, bucket, jupyter-lab

I've set up a project on GCP with a Compute Engine VM and Storage Bucket.
Access Scopes set to Allow full access to all Cloud APIs
Have set a default Region and Zone
I believe I have completed SSH authorization but not 100% sure given the documentation I've read.

I have ~100,000 photos on both my local machine that I managed to upload to a bucket and am now trying to run my algo using the VM connected jupyter lab.  My first thought was to create a list object from the bucket object.  After 90 min, I tried to do the same but with my local folder.  After failing at that, I attempted to mount the bucket on the VM instance though, I failed at that too (i'd rather not go this rout anyway since I'd have to copy the files which seems nuts).

i've used this with different commands `!gsutil ls gs://my_bucket`

`from google.cloud import storage`

`bucket_name = "my_bucket"`

`storage_client = storage.Client()`

`bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)`

I'm new to all this, have read through more GCP documentation pages than I can count and you would be disgusted with me about how much time I've given this...please help!

Answer (score 0):

If the issue is about how to access the Cloud Storage from within a VM instance, you can access Cloud Storage using different methods, the easiest one is using the gsutil tool on your instance. Please refer to the installation guide where you can find step by step instructions: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil_install.

After you have the tool installed you have a set of commands that you can use to interact with Cloud Storage, its buckets and objects. the most common uses are as below (with code samples available in multiple languages):

- Listing Buckets: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/listing-buckets.
- Getting Bucket’s information: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/getting-bucket-information
- Listing Objects: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/listing-objects
- Downloading Objects: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/downloading-objects
- Uploading Objects: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects